# Is it possible to select from an alias in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a table alias named `tbl`, and I want to select from that. But I am unable to do this. I know that my code is not correct nor optimized, but I am simply testing the MySQL `CASE`.

```
select
case
when exists (select username from tbl) then 'Username Exists'
else 'Username does not exist'
end
from (select 1 as id, 'bob' as username, 'pass' as password) as tbl
```

I get the error:  `Table 'users.tbl' doesn't exist in database users`.

Comment: You didn't use any physical table in your SQL query! Do you have table named [tbl] or synonym of database table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have that error because there's no physical table involved in the query, because `tbl` is just the alias you created.
If you want just to test if your username exists, execute this query:

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN id = 1 THEN 'Username Exists' ELSE 'Username does not exist'
END
FROM (SELECT 1 AS id, 'bob' AS username, 'pass' AS password) AS tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
select
     case
         when exists (select username from tbl where  username = 'bob' and  password = 'pass') then 'Username Exists'
     else 'Username does not exist'
     end as existanse_column
from  tbl
limit 1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14521/7)

Comment: `tbl` is not a physical query. If it would be, your query could work, but it's not this case.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano check my demo .